# Getting unknown email address added along with my reply

Tags: support, jobs, email

Well, I have been using Stack Overflow Careers for applying to jobs. I have my Gmail account associated with the SO account so whenever some recruiter contacts me, I see an email and a notification when I open SO. Everything is fine till this part.

**Problem I am facing:**

I am using a predefined signature in my Gmail account. So, I usually consider replying to the messages I receive via my Gmail account instead of logging in SO and replying. I don't know from where, I see one email address (which is not mine) getting attached just below my signature every time I am sending a reply. It's only getting added when I am replying from my Gmail account. (I haven't considered replying using my SO account as of yet). I have sent a cover letter using the website and it was sent fine without any problem but the problem arises when I am using Gmail to send a reply. Does anyone know what could be the problem? I don't want to send anything weird to my prospective employers.

Screenshot of the problem. The email address encircled in red below is getting automatically added. I have no idea from where it is getting added.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the problem?

Comment: @AlexWarren Added the screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

That email address *is* contained in the content of the email you sent. I can send you the exact email content we received, if that helps. I can tell you that underneath your phone number, you're sending us HTML like this:

```
<span style="font-family:&quot;Maiandra GD&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:#1f497d">
<a href="mailto:j*******@********.***.edu" target="_blank"></a></span>
```

The plain text version of your email simply contains the email address immediately under the phone number.

I guess maybe Gmail's signature editor is hiding it from you because the content of the `<a>` tag is empty. I'd delete the whole thing and paste in some plain text to create a fresh signature so you can be sure nothing is hiding in there.

Comment: Can you please message me the content of the email that you are getting from my gmail?

Comment: @John Email sent.